# TypeScript changing type definition of a function after importing it to another file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a custom hook called `useDropdownSelection`. It's fairly simple. Here's the code:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export const useDropdownSelection = (initialValue: string) => {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState<string>(initialValue)

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement>) => {
    const target = event.target as HTMLElement
    setSelectedOption(target.innerText)
  }

  return [selectedOption, handleClick]
}
```

As you can see, the `handleClick` function is of type `(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement>) => void`

But when I import it to my index.tsx, the `handleClick` function, for whatever reason, becomes of type `string | ((event: MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement, MouseEvent>) => void)`

```
const [selectedDropdownOption, handleDropdownClick] = useDropdownSelection('Most upvotes') // const handleDropdownClick: string | ((event: MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement, MouseEvent>) => void). WHY?
```

Why is this happening?

I assume it has something to do with the fact that I'm returning an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you don't specify that `useDropdownSelection` is going to return array of specific types for each indexes, so TS assumes that each index may contain both callback and string value.
check example below:

```js
const f = (s: string) => {
  const n: number = 5;
  return [s, n];
}
const result = f('s');
```

`result` is a `(string | number)[]` type. To explicitly inform that it's going to be [string, number] you have to implement it like below:

```js
const f = (s: string): [string, number] => {
  const n: number = 5;
  return [s, n];
}
const result = f('s'); // type is [string, number]
```

Syntax presented above is similar to one that is implemented by useState.

So in your example explicitly type return value of a hook:

```js
export const useDropdownSelection = (initialValue: string): [string, (event: MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement, MouseEvent>) => void] => {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

> If you are returning an array in your Custom Hook, you will want to avoid type inference as TypeScript will infer a union type (when you actually want different types in each position of the array).

What you need to do if you want to avoid the union type is using a const assertion:

```
return [selectedOption, handleClick] as const;
```

Now **selectedOption** and **handleClick** will keep respectively their type.

Docs: https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/hooks/#custom-hooks